# iPhone Core Data - cannot fulfill a fault error

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have three classes, A, B and C. A is the main class.

When the user wants to see the list of all objects that were purchased, Class B is called from A and shows the list of objects in a core data entity.

Inside class B, the user can buy new objects (in-app purchase). When the user wants to buy another object, class C is called.

When class C is called, a new object is created on the core data entity using

```
anObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Objects" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

this object is then assigned to a local reference on Class C, using something like

```
self.object = anObject;
```

this object variable was declared like this:

```
.h
MyObjects *object;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyObjects *object;

and @synthesized on .m
```

MyObjects is a core data class representing the entity.

In theory, object will retain anything assigned to it, so the line **self.object = anObject** I typed previously will retain anObject reference on self.object, right?

The problem is that when I try to access self.object in the same class after buying the new object, I receive an error "CoreData could not fulfill a fault for XXX", where XXX is exactly self.object.

At no point in the code there's any object removal from the database. The only operation to the database I could identify was a saving operation done by another class moments before the crash. The save is done by something like

```
if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) ...
```

Is there any relation? what may be causing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CoreData manages the lifetime of managed objects and you should not retain and release them. If you want to keep a reference to the object so that it can be retrieved later then you have to store the object's id (obtained using -[NSManagedObject objectID]). Then use that to retrieve the object later using -[NSManagedObjectContext objectWithID:].

Make sure you understand about CoreData faulting. Read the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html).

Comment: OK. Now I am doing what you said. I save the objectID reference when I create the object and then I retrieve it using objectWithID and it is still crashing at the same line, that is, exactly one line after I retrieve the object and I try to set its properties.

Comment: We will need to see the code for when you are storing the id and then retrieving the object later.

Comment: the problem is this: if I print to console the object I get after retrieving it using objectWithID is like this: **<Objects: 0x1ba900> (entity: Objects; id: 0x1b6ca0 <x-coredata://AA1AA912-2841-4F84-A174-E2154F09243A/Objects/p38> ; data: <fault>)** that I suppose is a fault. The problem now is how I "unfault" that...

Comment: You don't need to do anything. Just access any of its properties and CoreData will handle it for you. PLEASE read and understand the documentation on faults.

Comment: What? What's now working? The error says cannot fullfill fault error.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue a few days ago (using NSFetchedResultsController) where I was placing my fetchedObjects into an array and gathering attributes to populate tables from the array objects. It seems that if the objects in the array are faulted, you cannot unfault it unless you are acting on the direct object.  In my case, I solved the issue by taking the lines of code in question and calling `[[_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath] someAttribute]`.  I would assume that doing something similar would fix your problem as well.  It seems a bit tedious to need to fetch from the managedObjectContext to obtain a faulted value, but this was the only way I could personally get past the issue.

Comment: thanks. Can you translate that? What do you mean by "objects in the array are faulted" and why does that happens? Do you mean my self.object can point to an invalid object even if is being retained and no operation to delete it was done? I cannot understand that. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  To save memory, Core Data attribute and relationships are often faulted when not in use.  In short, the attributes are compressed.  The error you are getting isn't saying that your Core Data object is gone (it's still there in your database), just that it can't read specific information about it because it can't unfault the attribute, something Core Data must do. [This faulting guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html) gives a good example what it means when the data is faulted

Comment: so, how do I access the object again? I have done as suggested by Robin, that is, I am storing the objectID of the object and then, when I want to retrieve the object, I am getting it with objectWithID but the object I get is faulted again.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to reply, but it looks like you got things working.  So I'm glad to see that =]

Answer (score 1):

Core Data is responsible for managing the lifetime of managed objects in memory. It's really important to understand Managed Object Contexts - Read the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html).

Apple also provides an entire troubleshooting section [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTroubleshooting.html), and it contains among other things the causes for your error. But it's really only useful if you understand how core data works.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely error is that the object you are saving does not belong to the managed object context.

Say you use the same object on different threads and those different threads use different managed object context, then this will happen.